# What programming language is Init.goldfish in android written in?

Tags: android, init

This's a part of the .bashrc from Ubuntu (apparently same language) :

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

So,what is that language? It has a fi keyword in it. And how can I learn that language? I prefer online tutorials or source code repositories to books.

Comment: It's [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). Search google for "shell scripting".

Comment: It's a shell script for `bash`, `.bashrc` is run when there's a new terminal window/interactive session. Note that searching for something like `what is bashrc` would lead to a lot of resources.

Comment: This ist the Unix Command Language - bash 

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

or 1000.0000.0000 other tutotials :D.

Comment: a bash tutorial is at: http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php

Answer (score 0):

It's UNIX shell script, the standardized scripting language implemented by shells such as bash. It's powerful for automating small tasks on UNIX based systems, such as Linux or Android.

Googling something like `unix shell script tutorial` will give you plenty of tutorials.

Comment: Not sure I'd go so far as to call it "standardized", since different shells implement different functionality.

Comment: Different shells indeed implement different dialects, but the one implemented by Bash is at least in large parts compatible with the the POSIX shell command language (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html).